# R_trigger macro excel if button is clicked

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to this with macro in Excel. I want to create a macro for a rounded rectangle which when I click will write a bool value (true) to a cell. Then when a value in another cell is changed should the macro write the another bool variable (false) to the same cell which it wrote to earlier.

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. This is only a Problem Solving forum but not code writing Forum.

Comment: What do you mean by Rounded Rectangle? what do you mean by chnage in another cell?

Comment: just a figure that i will click on. there are two cells, i have connected excel to a OPC server and to a PLC so when i click on the figure i want the cell to write true to one cell. Then the PLC will start a engine and when that is started will antother cell increase by one. when that happen i want the macro to write false agian in the cell that it first wrote true

Comment: `I want to create a macro` so what's stopping you?

Comment: Will there be any Time delay for the PLC to start and increase the other cell? If No try the code mentioned in my answer.

Comment: the  delay is around 200 ms

Answer (score 0):

Try this and Assign this macro to your figure by right clicking and Assign macro

```
Sub AssignBool()
Dim IncValue As Integer
IncValue = Worksheets("UrsheerNamehere").Range("UrIncrcell").Value 'like Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
Worksheets("UrSheet").Range("").Value = True 'like Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value = True
Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")) 'Waits for 10 seconds
If (IncValue = IncValue + 1) Then
 Worksheets("UrSheet").Range("").Value = True
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks i belive that would do the job, but the data that the macro writes to the cell is not valid. If i write for example FALSE in the cell it work but not when the macro does it. any suggestions?

Comment: What values you are expecting? If you want to add string try "TRUE" instead of True.

Comment: when i go to format and check it, it only stand general and no specific number format. But when i type true <- like this in the cell it works.

Comment: Then use the same in macro instead of book value I specified

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if the codes fits to your needs and working

Comment: yes it worked, thanks a lot ! even though the it was more of a code writing help than problem :)